# PHP + Jquery + cypress.io setup in a classical MVC application. How to?

Tags: php, jquery, cypress

At work we have an application built with php (codeigniter) and lots of jquery, don't ask :)
It's not a modern app, is a classical MVC PHP app. Would it be possible to integrate cypress.io with as less changes to the current estructure?

My idea was to install cypress.io in a separate folder and run the tests from there
is it a feasible solution?

Comment: This is not a good practice ! See the documentation of Cypress.io !

Comment: I know is not a good practice and I've read the docs. I would like to be working in a modern application but I'm not. That's why I'm looking for a pragmatic solution.

Comment: What is not good practice about it @Jboucly? Seems reasonable to me. I've done exactly as described and it works great. Sometimes you need to test the legacy as it is *then* refactor.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** - you can test any web application with cypress.io.

I have done exactly as you describe.

**How?** - You can

- add a folder to your existing source control,
- run your development web-server as you normally would,
- [set the `baseUrl`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Global) to your development server (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/`),
- write some tests & assertions that use your existing markup to find buttons, text etc,
- and run cypress to test your app.

Take a look at ["getting started" in the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html)

You might also want to look at [asdf-vm](https://asdf-vm.com/) now that you will have node & php